# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Подскажите в чем проблема. Мой ajax запрос

```
            getData(){
        axios.post("/admin/statistic/topsample/",{
            date_start:this.date_start,
            date_end:this.date_end
        })
            .then((msg)=>{
                this.data = msg.data;
                console.log(this.data);
            })
    }
},
```

Route

```
Route::get("/topstore","StatisticController@topstore")->name("topstore");
Route::post("/topsample","StatisticController@topsample")->name("topsample");
```

Comment: Заголовок уже отвечает на вопрос "в чем проблема". Для перевода на русский язык, можешь использовать любой автоматический переводчик (например, Google Translate).

Comment: Может нужно очистить кэш? php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache

Answer (score 0):

Ваша API:

```
/admin/statistic/topsample/
```

не поддерживает метод Get...

На бекенде добавьте метод get к вашему запросу что б на фронте иметь доступ к этому методу